# How to perform linear regression from different csv?

Tags: python, regression, jupyter

I want to perform multilinear regression using two variables from different dataframes.

```
Y1 = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Y.csv') 
Y1 = pd.DataFrame(Y,columns=['Year','JJASON','JJA','JAS','ASO','SON'])
Y1=  Y[Y['Year'].between(1984,2020, inclusive="both")]

X1 = pd.read_csv (r'C:\X1.csv') 
X1 = pd.DataFrame(X1,columns=['Year','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])
X1=  X1[X2['Year'].between(1984,2020, inclusive="both")]

X2 = pd.read_csv (r'C:\X2.csv',na_values= 'NaN') 
X2 = pd.DataFrame(Chukchi,columns=['Year','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'])
X2=X2[X2['Year'].between(1984,2020, inclusive="both")]
```

So far I am able to read the .csv files and perform regression using one variable, X1.

```
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X1(-1,1), Y1)
```

However, most of the examples I find online on multilinear regression uses two Xs from one csv. Hence they use:

`df [[X1,X2]]`

I am really new in python programming. How do I perform multilinear regression using 2 different X from different .csv? Thank you.

I want to perform multilinear regression in March for X1 and X2 and JJASON in Y1 only.
[Attached is the link to Y, X1, and X2 data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gp3fptkxu3g8jzg/Data.zip?dl=0)

Comment: So what I did instead is to perform concatenation of X1 and X2 into a new X then use it in the new linear regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just regressing `JJASON` in Y and `March` in X1 and X2, you can do this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

LR = LinearRegression()
Y = Y[['JJASON']]
X = np.hstack(X1[['March']],X2[['March']])
LR.fit(Y,X)
```

Comment: Sorry for the less details. I was actually regressing JJASON in Y and March in X1 and X2 only.

Comment: Hey if you check your y.csv there are no such columns